# When is Spring @Conditional checked

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inversion-of-control

We are using Spring Boot 2.6.13 with Java 11 and our application has to connect to an external service. On some environments, we have to use a corporate proxy.

In order to make the application flexible, I thought of creating 2 beans. One with a proxy, the other without.

```
@Bean
public HttpHost getProxyHost() {
    return null;
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "application.proxy-url")
public HttpHost getProxyHost(
        ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration
) {
    return new HttpHost(
            applicationConfiguration.getProxyUrl(),
            applicationConfiguration.getProxyPort(),
            applicationConfiguration.getProxyScheme()
    );
}
```

I would think that Spring only makes the second bean if the `proxy-url` field is filled in. However, it creates the bean every time. Problem there is that if `applicationConfiguration.getProxyUrl()` returns null, a NullPointerException is thrown and the application is unable to startup.

There is a solution where I use an if statement, check the value and return null if the url is null. But I thought this IoC way would look cleaner.

I have tried searching online on how/when Spring is checking the `@Conditional` annotations, but haven't found much (without going through it's source code).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> However, it creates the bean every time.

As you are passing `@Primary`. Remove it and see, it should only create it when you are setting `application.proxy-url` in your `application.proeprties/.yml`

In order to make sure that `applicationConfiguration.getProxyUrl()` does not return null you can make this class `@Validated`

This way, if your `applicationConfiguration` has null/empty fields it will stop you there itself at the time of loading of your application.

```
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application")
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @NotBlank
    private final String proxyUrl;

    @NotBlank
    private final String proxyPort;

    @NotBlank
    private final String proxyScheme;

}
```